# Delphi ActiveX in IE - Showmodal is not very modal

Tags: delphi

I have an active form written in delphi, hosted in IE.
When I popup a Tform with showmodal i can still interact with the activex form behind it.

I am pretty sure my app never used to do this.

I have noted mixed results when playing with popupmode pmAuto and pmNone, but not the answer I am looking for.
Please help!